# convert ctable to rtf/word/odt etc

Tags: tables, lyx

I need to convert ctables, like the following, into a format for a word processor (MS Word, OOWrite etc.) It should be an editable table but in worse case, an img would be also fine...

```
\ctable[
    cap = {Beispielverteilung der Infrastrukturmerkmale},
    caption = {Beispielverteilung der Infrastrukturmerkmale},
label = BspInfra,
width = 87mm,
pos   = ht,
center,
]{lrrr}{
}{
    \FL
    & Merkmal 1 & Merkmal 2 & Merkmal 3 \NN
    \cmidrule(l){1-4}
    Haushalt 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\NN
    Haushalt 2 & 0 & 0 & 1\NN
    Haushalt 3 & 0 & 1 & 1\NN
    Haushalt 4 & 1 & 1 & 0\NN
\NN
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Normalisierte Matrix $ R^{-\frac{1}{2}} \Sigma C^{-\frac{1}{2}} $}\NN
    Haushalt 1 & 0,500 & 0,000 & 0,408\NN
    Haushalt 2 & 0,000 & 0,000 & 0,577\NN
    Haushalt 3 & 0,000 & 0,500 & 0,408\NN
    Haushalt 4 & 0,500 & 0,500 & 0,000\NN
\LL
}
```

I tried to convert that with LyX to an OpenDocument format, but I get a corrupt file. I also tried the to convert it to an html document, which also doesn't work... :-\

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Normally you should be able to import it into a Spreadsheet editor specifying the separator character (`'&'` in your case) and ignoring specified lines. The formula won't show properly in MS Office Excel, but with OpenOffice Calc, after minimal editing it should be just fine (e.g. replacing `\` with `%` if I'm not mistaken). Then you can put the spreadsheet into a MS Word/ OO Writer file.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the above file as shown below, and then use [LaTeX2rtf](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) to convert to a format that you can use in Word.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
   % above contents here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also [tex4ht](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) which can also convert to OpenOffice or MWWord format. From [the documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html)

> A translation for an OpenDocument format can be requested by the ‘\oolatex’ command. ...
>
> The OpenDocument code employs MathML for formulas, and XSL-FO for formatting. It can be viewed by the OpenOffice word processor which, in turn, can export RTF and other MicroSoft-based formats ...
>
> A command of the form ‘htlatex filename "html,word" "symbol/!" "-cvalidate"’ asks for HTML output tuned toward MicroSoft Word. Such a format, however, relies on bitmaps for mathematical formulas.